# Не получается вызвать SHBrowseInfo

Tags: winapi, ассемблер, masm32

Никак не получается вызвать функцию SHBrowseForFolder.

```
WndProc proc hWnd:HWND, uMsg:UINT, wParam:WPARAM, lParam:LPARAM
    local rect:RECT
    local pt:POINT
    ;local buf[128]:BYTE
    ;mov buf[0], 0
    local bi:BROWSEINFO
    .IF uMsg==WM_DESTROY
        invoke PostQuitMessage,NULL
    .ELSEIF uMsg==WM_CREATE
        invoke CreateWindowEx, NULL, ADDR BtnClName, ADDR TextButton, WS_CHILD or BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON or WS_VISIBLE, 20, 20, 100, 50, hWnd, ButtonID, hInstance, 0
        mov hwndButton, eax
        invoke ShowWindow, hwndButton, SW_SHOWNORMAL
    .ELSEIF uMsg==WM_COMMAND
        mov eax, wParam
        ;.IF ax==ButtonID
        ;   invoke BrowseForFolder, hWnd, ADDR buf, ADDR TextButton, ADDR TextButton
        ;.ENDIF
        invoke SHBrowseForFolder, ADDR bi
    .ELSE
        invoke DefWindowProc,hWnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam   
        ret
    .ENDIF
    xor eax,eax
    ret
WndProc endp
end start
```

Библиотеки вроде бы все подключил:

```
include c:\masm32\include\windows.inc
include c:\masm32\include\user32.inc
include c:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include c:\masm32\include\gdi32.inc
include c:\masm32\include\comdlg32.inc
include c:\masm32\include\shell32.inc
includelib c:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib
includelib c:\masm32\lib\user32.lib
includelib c:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\gdi32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\comdlg32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\shell32.lib
```

Линкер выдает вот такую ошибку. 
[image: Вот такая ошибка получается]

Строку стираю, с вызовом этой функции, все работает нормально. Помогите, который день уже воюю, все без толку.

Comment: проверьте пути библиотек, у вас часть includelib задана как абсолютные пути, а часть как относительные, судя по ошибке линкер не может найти нужную либу, возможно стоит вместо `includelib \masm32\lib\gdi32.lib` писать `includelib c:\masm32\lib\gdi32.lib`

Comment: Вот знаете что! Вы думаете, вы такой умный? ДА! Это так и есть) Огромное спасибо вам! Проблема была именно в этом

Comment: Блин, теперь оно просто закрывает окно... Почему же интересно....